# Inequality using coefficients of Taylor development of bounded holomorphic funciton

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: D(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function on $D(0,1)$ and let $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n z^n$ be its Taylor series at $0$.

We suppose that the Taylor development converges in $D(0,1)$, that $f(0) \geq 0$ and that $\forall z\in D: |f(z)| \leq 1$.

I try to prove that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{|a_n|}{ 3^n} \leq 1 \, .$$

*What I did:*

Since $\frac{1}{3} \in  D(0,1)$, $|f(\frac{1}{3}) | \leq 1$ which means 
$|\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{a_n}{ 3^n} |\leq 1 $.
However what I need to prove is stronger since  $|\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{a_n}{ 3^n}| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{|a_n|}{ 3^n} $.

Could you please help with any technique or theorems I could use?

Comment: The condition $f(0) \ge 0$ looks unnecessary, because you can always consider $\lambda f(z)$ instead, with a suitable $\lambda$ of modulus $1$. – Or should it be $f(0) = 0$?

Comment: Actually it is a condition of the problem. I thought it could be used to prove that $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, since $a_0=f(0) \geq 0 $. $ f(0) =0 $ is  not mandatory in my case

Comment: $a_n \ge 0$ need not be true, as $f(z) = \frac 12 - \frac i2 z$ is a possible function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is “Bohr's theorem on power series” and
the number $\frac 13$ is the so-called “Bohr radius,” after the Danish 
mathematician (and soccer player) [Harald Bohr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_Bohr):

> Let $f$ be holomorphic in the unit disk $\Bbb D$ with power series
>   $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n $, and $|f(z)| < 1$ for all
>   $|z| \in \Bbb D$. Then
>   $$
>  \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n z^n| \le 1 \quad \text{for } |z| \le \frac 13 \, .
> $$
>   (The number $\frac 13$ cannot be replaced by any larger number.)

The following proof is taken from [Why Bohr got interested in his radius and what it has led to](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/dragan/respub/Coll-Seip-handout-12-2009.pdf), which also contains more information about the history
of this theorem and further developments.

The [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem)
states that
$$
 \frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f
(z)|^2} \le \frac{1}{1-|z|^2} \, .
$$
In particular for $z=0$ it follows that
$$
 |a_1| \le 1 - |a_0|^2 \, .
$$

The crucial idea now is that the same relationship holds for higher
derivatives as well:
$$ \tag{*}
 |a_n| \le 1 - |a_0|^2 \quad \text{for } n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots 
$$
Then
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|a_n|}{3^n} \le |a_0| + (1 - |a_0|^2) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n} = |a_0| + \frac{1 - |a_0|^2}{2} \\
= 1 -\frac{(1- |a_0|)^2}{2} \le 1 \, .
$$

So it remains to prove $(*)$: For fixed $n\ge 1$, let $\omega$ be
a $n^{\text{th}}$ root of unity and set
$$
 g(z) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(\omega^j z) = a_0 + a_n z^n
 + a_{2n} z^{2n} + \ldots = h(z^n)
$$
where
$$
 h(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{kn} z^k 
$$
is holomorphic in the unit disk, and also $|h(z)| \le 1$.
Therefore we can apply the Schwarz-Pick theorem to $h$ and conclude
that
$$
 |a_n| = |h'(0)| \le 1 - |h(0)|^2 = 1 - |a_0|^2 \, .
$$
This finishes the proof.

*Remark:* The condition $f(0) \ge 0$ is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!